# Microsoft Graph API V3 - Identity Provider

Tags: authentication, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way of using the V3 Microsoft Graph Java SDK with the Authorization Header? In the V1 and V2, i had this:

```
IAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new IAuthenticationProvider() {
    @Override
    public void authenticateRequest(IHttpRequest request) {
        request.addHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME, OAUTH_BEARER_PREFIX + accessToken);
    }
};
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider).buildClient();
```

But using the V3 SDK and the ICoreAuthenticationProvider , the only client I can create is the OKHTTP one, and not the IGraphServiceClient ,  and I lose all the "Microsoft API" (i get a string response, that I need to "unmarshall"... )

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Graph Java SDK now leverages [azure-identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview) to improve the authentication experience. To integrate with the Microsoft Identity platform use Microsoft Authentication Library for Java ([MSAL4J](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java)). This library provides support for [more authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java) and improves the configuration experience.  To upgrade your application do the following:

- Remove any dependency on `microsoft-graph-auth` and replace them by one of the providers available in MSAL4J
- Reconsider the need for custom authentication providers (implementation of `IAuthenticationProvider` or `ICoreAuthenticationProvider`) that might be part of your project and use a provider available in azure-identity whenever possible.

In your case for example, if you were using client credential flow, you would replace the above sample with this:

```
final ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
.clientId(CLIENT_ID)
.clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
.tenantId(TENANT_GUID)
.build();
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(SCOPES, clientSecretCredential);
final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
```

Please see here for more examples to [upgrade your authentication providers:](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java/blob/4139f70beba18877fbb2dc307700df006d303edb/docs/upgrade-to-v3-auth.md)

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.